# Delphi synchronizing panels order with table order

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am generating panels at runtime. I have a panel on the form, then I have inside it a scrollBox alClient. Inside that scrollBox I add panels dynamically. They all belong to the Scrollbox, and I align them to bottom after I generate them. So they appear one above the other.

The code I use follows:

```
Procedure TMain.AdaugaElement(numar:integer; tip:string);
var
  pan:TPanel;
  semn:TShape;
  pos:TPoint;
  lab:TLabel;
  myimg:TImage;
  bmpsep, dest:TBitmap;
begin

  pan:=TPanel.Create(self);
  pan.Parent:=ScrollBox1;
  pan.Align:=alBottom;
  pan.Height:=50;
  pan.Name:='Layeru'+IntToStr(numar);
  pan.Caption:='Elementul '+IntToStr(numar);
  pan.Font.Color:=$00004F4F;
  pan.Font.Quality:=fqAntialiased;
  pan.Color:=$0080FFFF;
  pan.OnMouseDown:=layerRowMouseDown;
  pan.ParentColor:=false;
  pan.ParentBackground:=false;
  pan.Color:=clWhite;

  Pos:= pan.ClientOrigin;

  vt.AppendRecord([vt.RecordCount+1,Pan.name,numar,numar,0 ,0, 20,20,800,600,pan.Caption,tip]);

  lab:=TLabel.Create(self);
  lab.Parent:=pan;
  lab.Left:=54;
  lab.Top:=16;
  lab.Font.Size:=10;
  lab.Font.Color:=clBlack;
  lab.Font.Style:=[];
  lab.Font.Quality:=fqAntialiased;
  lab.Caption:=IntToStr(numar);
  Randomize;
  lab.Name:='Layernumber'+IntToStr(numar);

  semn:=TShape.Create(self);
  semn.Parent:=pan;
  semn.Left:=3;
  semn.Top:=3;
  semn.Height:=44;
  semn.Width:=44;
  semn.Pen.Color:=$00009D9D;
  semn.Brush.Color:=clWhite;

  myimg:=TImage.Create(self);
  myimg.Width:=42;
  myimg.Height:=42;
  myimg.Left:=4;
  myimg.Top:=4;
  myImg.Visible:=true;
  myimg.Proportional:=true;
  myimg.Stretch:=true;
  myImg.Parent:=pan;

  SelectLayerPan(numar);
end;
```

- `SelectLayerPan` procedure simulates a selected row in a table, so when I add a new panel, it shows as 'selected' (it 'deselects' all panels then it 'selects' the new panel)
- `vt` is a `VirtualTable` where I input information about the generated panels

So I add panels like this:

```
AdaugaElement(1,'type1');
AdaugaElement(2,'type1');
AdaugaElement(3,'type1');
AdaugaElement(4,'type1');
```

Next, I want to move panels among themselves using the mouse. So initially I have added:

```
- panel5
- panel4
- panel3
- panel2
- panel1
```

*(in this order)*

Then using the mouse, I drag panel1 and drop it between panel4 and panel5. So they will appear as:

```
- panel5
- **panel1**
- panel4
- panel3
- panel2
```

*(in this order)*

This drag-drop is done in layerRowMouseDown.

But, since in the virtualTable I have the info about panels (in the original order), so

```
record1: panel1  pos:1
record2: panel2  pos:2
record3: panel3  pos:3
record4: panel4  pos:4
record5: panel5  pos:5
```

I must identify the moved panels record and update it so it will reflect its new position, so the VirtualTable must look like this:

```
record1: panel1  pos:4
record2: panel2  pos:1
record3: panel3  pos:2
record4: panel4  pos:3
record5: panel5  pos:5
```

How can I do this?

I mean, how do I detect where the panel ended up when I drop it? Or maybe how do I get the order of the panels in their container (ScrollBox1)?

So far I tried using `FindVCLWindow(pos)` to identify the panels (and their order in the scrollBox) using the starting position and multiples of height of the panels, but when there are more panels, and they are no longer visible directly (without scrolling), it obviously stops working correctly.

So that is not a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Top` property of the panels in the `TScrollBox` seems to be the only reliable indicator for the order of the panels. To find the order of the panels you could assign the panels temporarily to a list and then sort that list on the Top property. Now you would have them in the same order in the list as they appear in the scrollbox.

The following is just an example of sorting with a temporary list. You will need to modify it to suit your purpose.

```
procedure TForm6.UpdateRecords;
var
  Comparer: IComparer<TMyPanel>;
  i: integer;
  s: string;
begin
  Comparer := TDelegatedComparer<TMyPanel>.Create(
    function (const A, B: TMyPanel):integer
    begin
      Result := A.Top - B.Top;
    end);
  TempPanelList := TMyPanelList.Create(Comparer);
  try
    for i := 0 to ScrollBox1.ControlCount-1 do
      TempPanelList.Add(TMyPanel(ScrollBox1.Controls[i]));
    TempPanelList.Sort;
    for i := 0 to TempPanelList.Count-1 do
    begin
      // replace this with your own code, something like in next snippet
      s := s + ', ' + inttostr(TempPanelList.items[i].Tag);
      Label1.Caption := s;
      //
    end;
  finally
    TempPanelList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Then to get a reference between a panel in the list and corresponding record in `vt` you could use the `tag` property at creation of the panels. You seem to pass a parameter `numar` to the AdaugaElement procedure, so assuming this could work as an index to `vt`, you could assign this `numar` to `pan.Tag`.

Finally to update the `pos` fields in `vt` you could assign the new positions of the panels in a loop where you assign the index of the TPanel in the TempPanelList to pos in the `vt` record. **Note!** I don't know the proper syntax for working with `VirtualTable`

```
for i := 0 to TempPanelList.Count-1 do
begin
  vt[TPanel(TempPanelList[i]).Tag].pos := i;
end;
```

But your setup seems very fragile on many accounts, and the above doesn't help any of that. You are assigning the TMain instance (a form?) as the owner of all these TPanels, TShapes, TLabels and TImages. It becomes very messy when the user adds and deletes layers. I would instead create a composite class TLayerItem to hold everything related to one layer and a LayerManager class to manage the TLayerItems.

Comment: I did not use exactly your idea, however your answer got me inspired, and I found my solution. It is not using the panel tags, I use a label that is contained in the dynamic panel, and the major stuff that helps is using the vt (table). The spark idea that I used from you was the ordering by Top property of the panels. Thank you a lot

Answer (score -1):

This seems like an inefficient solution. Also, why reinvent the wheel?

What you're describing is very similar to how a toolbar works, only it's laid out vertically rather than horizontally. I'd look at the source for some toolbars and see if you couldn't use something that's already designed to do what you want. If nothing else, you'll get some good ideas how to implement what you're trying to do.

Alternatively, I'd look into using a TFlowPanel inside the scrollbox where you'd put your panels on the flowpanel rather than directly onto the scrollbox.

EDIT: I apologize to whomever downvoted this, but we're not allowed to point to off-site stuff, and I'm not about to post all of the code for several toolbar components here.

Comment: It's not re-inventing the wheel. There is no 'wheel' (component) that acts and does what I need it to do. So it is `inventing` the wheel rather than re-inventing it

Comment: upvote! TFlowPanel  save lifes if you use bottom positioning in scrollbox